# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/bytebuddy/matcher/ElementMatcher: net.bytebuddy.matcher.ElementMatcher after moving to spring-boot 3.2.2

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I moved a service from spring-boot **3.1.6** to **3.2.2** today and started getting the

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/bytebuddy/matcher/ElementMatcher: net.bytebuddy.matcher.ElementMatcher`

compile error. I compared the POMs and saw that hibernate went from **6.2.13.Final** to **6.4.1.Final** so I manually downgraded and the service compiles again.

Anyone experienced the same issue? I moved another service that went just fine (of course not completely the same as it uses a couple of different additional deps, but in general it's quite similar)

Comment: Generally this comes from to eager dependency management, something is pulling in another incompatible version of ByteBuddy. Figure out which one instead of downgrading other dependencies (which will lead to other issues with later upgrades).